# Response interceptor data incomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a weird problem that I cannot understand. I hope someone can help me.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/e9B6jc - for some reason, I cannot reproduce the situation in plunker, but since it's created, I leave it here to show the setup and data expected.

The setup is this:

- Server with an API.
- Server with the web interface with angular.

The process is like this:

1. I make a GET request to the API (`/api/employees/{guid}`) , which returns data like the employee.json in the plunker. I'm using *ngResouce* (angular-resource) to query the API.
2. It gets intercepted by the *HttpInterceptor*, which adds some required headers to the request.
3. When the server returns the data (server response), the response is again intercepted by the *HttpInterceptor*. It does some things and rejects or continues depending on the status.
4. When it continues, the data is simply passed back to the controller.

My problem is between 3 and 4: when the response is intercepted (3), I log the data (as shown in the script.js of the plunker, line 35) and, randomly, I get the `response.data.account.roles` empty. I'm sure that the roles array is not empty, because when I inspect the data in the Developer Tools (Google Chrome, Network tab), the response contains all data. Even in the API logs (on the server side) the roles array is not empty.

The weird thing is that when I log the intercepted response, the `response.data.account.roles` MAY be empty (yes, not always). However, if I log the object explicitly (using `response.data.account.roles`) the array is never empty.

In the UI, I use angular to show the full object (index.html of the plunker, line 17) and sometimes the account.roles is empty. I say sometimes because it happens when I reload the page. This, of course, causes problems in the UI, because the response.data.account.roles is sometimes empty, and I need it to set the selected items of a select element.

I did some tests:

- Put a breakpoint in angular-resource.js (where the response is executed) and the response.data contains all the expected roles.
- Put another breakpoint in angular.js, in $http(config).transformResponse (private method) and, again, the response (without parsing) is complete (the roles are present).
- Inside the httpInterceptor, if I do an angular.copy of the response object, the roles array is filled.

  ```
  var copy = angular.copy(response);
  // copy.data.account.roles.length > 0 = true
  // response.data.account.roles.length > 0 = false
  ```

In the first 2 tests, the responses contains the expected data, but, weird enough, in the UI (and the interceptor) the roles array is empty.

I hope someone can enlighten me, because I can't figure it out :(. By the way, I asked this question in google groups too -> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/ecJmyjBOvvc

Thanks to everyone who reads this.

The plunker code is this:

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('HttpInterceptor', function($rootScope, $log, $q, $injector, $location) {
  var interceptor = {
    request: onRequest,
    requestError: onRequestError,
    response: onResponse,
    responseError: onResponseError
  };
  return interceptor;

  function onRequest(config) {
    $log.debug('Entering request.');
    config.headers['Accept-Language'] = 'es-cl';
    if (config.url.endsWith('.html')) {
      return config;
    }
    config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    var token = 'token data that comes from server';
    if (!angular.isUndefined(token)) {
      config.headers.Authorization = token;
    }
    $log.debug('Leaving request.');
    return config;
  }

  function onRequestError(error) {
    $log.error('Request failed.', error);
  }

  function onResponse(response) {
    $log.info('Response success.');
    // Roles array is empty
    // Here, when the account is present, the roles array MAY be empty
    $log.debug('Intercepted response data:', response);
    if (response) {
      if (response.data) {
        if (response.data.account) {
          // Data shown correctly
          // Here, when the account is present, the roles array ALWAYS has data
          // (of course, only when the roles is not empty)
          if (response.data.account.roles) {
            $log.debug('Roles:', response.data.account.roles);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    var copy = angular.copy(response);
    // copy.data.account.roles.length > 0 = true
    // response.data.account.roles > 0 = false (sometimes)

    return response || $q.when(response);
  }
});
```

mainController.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http, JsonFactory) {
  JsonFactory.get(function(data) {
    $scope.employee = data;
  });
});
```

jsonFactory.js

```
angular.module('app').factory('JsonFactory', function($resource) {
  return $resource('employee.json');
});
```

employee.json (the expected server response)

```
{
  "id" : "employee-guid",
  "firstName" : "Test",
  "lastName" : "Subject",
  "nationalId" : "1-9",
  "account" : {
    "login" : "1-9",
    "email" : "a@a.com",
    "roles" : [
      {
        "id" : "role0-guid",
        "name" : "unpriv",
        "displayName" : "No permissions at all",
        "description" : "Some descriptive text"
      },
      {
        "id" : "role1-guid",
        "name" : "somepriv",
        "displayName" : "Some permissions",
        "description" : "Some descriptive text"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="jsonFactory.js"></script>
    <script src="mainController.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
      <div>
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <pre>{{ employee | json }}</pre>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Roles</h4>
        <pre>{{ employee.account.roles | json }}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Update 12-01-2016**

The `copy.data.account.roles` can be empty sometimes too.

I'm aware that `$log.debug|info|etc` doesn't show the current object state, so I used breakpoints to inspect the objects in Google Chrome.

Angular version is 1.4.

Comment: Can you check this in different browser FF/Chrome, which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @csharpfolk This happens in FF, Chrome and Opera. Angular version is 1.4 (added to the question too). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my problem... the thing is that a directive I'm using was removing the contents of the array.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to read this.